# How do I create a GA4 report showing event count when the events have unique/custom names?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

We have an event on our website that fires when a user watches a video. We're then passing the video's filename as an event via GTM. When I run debug mode in GTM, it fires properly and the filename is there. However, I can't figure out how to actually create a report in GA4 that shows all of these custom event names and the # of times they've been fired.

Here is the data showing properly in GTM debug:

[image]

[image]

How do I now pull this into a GA4 report so I can show all filenames and the count for each?

Answer (score 0):

### First : event should not be a file name

The datalayer spec might need to optimize.

Event should be `video-played`

and the file name should be a custom event parameter like `video_name` or `video_file`

### Second : The screenshot is only showing the datalayer.

DataLayer is a centralized information about tracking user action for Google Tag Manager.

The screenshot didn't show is there any data send to GA4 already.

Google Tag Manager is a transmitter. GA4 is some place receiving the data.

But it need to be configured in Google Tag Manager.

---

In the Google Tag Manager preview:

You should see one or more tags fired when the datalayer push that event.

If not : then we need to configure properly.

[image]